# PHP How to output Array from an variables

Tags: php

I have textfile as named 'ulfana.txt', and i want build JSON string from it.
content *Ulfana.txt*

```
EAAAAAYsX7TsBAG5Ps8MA0ZCQZC3QLawZB29jINrChL5hPflXxalBiGW7ZAwpvUIs7qIzshLBRjBFvzAFGnhO3cXtZAZChW6XxtUITHXe9Q3aH6mfiGLoSsoqpGXqktpx2EBRcOcCqVCyufI7q0abl5RaZB2lE4MkVwDaThCTonm07WZB1dxTu4xbwuDdwn6ZArPUjroQWAcwJWBZA0PGmZCUitB
```

PHP Codes :

```
<?php
    $tokens = file_get_contents('ulfana.txt'); //getting file content
    $fbid = '100011432913918'; //from $_SESSION['uid']
    echo '{ "token": "' . $tokens. '", "value": { "id": ' . $fbid . ', "name": "Ulfana.txt" } }';
?>
```

I want output like this

```
{ "token":"EAAAAAYsX7TsBAG5Ps8MA0ZCQZC3QLawZB29jINrChL5hPflXxalBiGW7ZAwpvUIs7qIzshLBRjBFvzAFGnhO3cXtZAZChW6XxtUITHXe9Q3aH6mfiGLoSsoqpGXqktpx2EBRcOcCqVCyufI7q0abl5RaZB2lE4MkVwDaThCTonm07WZB1dxTu4xbwuDdwn6ZArPUjroQWAcwJWBZA0PGmZCUitB", "value": { "id": 100011432913918, "name": "Alif Mdza" } }
```

Comment: You shouldn't concatenate the echo function when making your string. Simply concatenate the variable without echo.

Comment: You want to use `json_encode()` on something instead of concatenating strings. Not sure on what as your question is pretty unclear...

Comment: How can i solved this problem

Comment: Solve what problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
$array=["token"=>$echo,"value"=>["id"=>$fbid,"name"=>'Ulfana.txt']];
$array=json_encode($array);
print_r($array);
```

It give output as

[image]

Comment: you can just `echo` an encoded JSON. no _need_ to `print_r`. Not that it's wrong or anything.

Comment: No i am just printing `$array` value.

Comment: Thank you. It can be combined with file_get_contents

Comment: creating json string

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    $tokens = file_get_contents('ulfana.txt');
    $fbid = '100011432913918';
    echo "{ \"token\": \"" . $tokens . "\", \"value\": { \"id\": " . $fbid . ", \"name\": \"Ulfana.txt\" } }";
?>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.